# request.FILES empty uploading image on Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here is my HTML sending the request, printing `request.FILES` return `<MultiValueDict: {}>`.
Also i would ask how can i save my charged picture (is ok to only `form.save()`?)

```
<form action="send_news" method="POST" encrypt="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %} {{ form.as_p }}
    <p>
        <label for="news_title">Your name: </label>
        <input id="news_title" type="text" name="news_title" value="newtitle">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="news_small_description">Your name: </label>
        <input name="news_small_description" id="news_small_description" value="news_small_description">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="news_description">Your name: </label>
        <input name="news_description" id="news_description" value="news_description">
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="news_image">Your name: </label>
        <input id="news_image" type="file" class="" name="news_image">
    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

printing request.FILES return `<MultiValueDict: {}>`.
Also i would ask how can i save my charged picture (is ok to only `form.save()`?)

Comment: Did you add a file before hitting the submit button? Why do you extract all these elements from `cleaned_data`?

Comment: Are you using a webserver in front of django that might be interfering with the posted data?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes i add a image before hitting the button. I extract all these elements becouse i need them to create my New object

Comment: @TomDalton no i'm not

Comment: i think i'm mistaking the code to upload the image

Comment: Are you able to see the image file/data being posted by your browser as part of the request (e.g. in the chrome dev tools)?

Comment: Thanks!  you already get the point. FANTASTIC! in 3 min i can accept your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using `encrypt` but you need to use `enctype`

e.g.

```
<form action="send_news" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

See [What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean) for more info if needed.